# Run a code of the apparent selection only

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am using the below code to open any local file or hyperlink found on my `Selection`. 
The code itself run as expected, But If applied an autoFilter on the sheet and I select manually non continuous cells on the same column, 
I found out that my selection contains also the hidden cells in-betweens and subsequently unwanted links are opened. 
**My question**, Is How to modify the below code to run on (includes) the apparent selection only?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
        ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
 
Sub OpenDocument2() 'ShellExecute
 
    Dim cel As Range, El, arrCel
 
    For Each cel In Selection.Cells
        If cel.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            ShellExecute 0, "open", (cel.Hyperlinks(1).Address), "", "", 1
        Else
            arrCel = Split(cel.value, vbLf)
            For Each El In arrCel
                ShellExecute 0, "open", (El), "", "", 1
            Next El
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Test if `cell.EntireRow.Hidden`

Comment: @Tim Williams , It works. I did not thinks the answer is just additional one line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```vb
dim rg As Range: set rg = Selection
For Each cel In rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

which only returns visible, i.e. filtered cells

Comment: Using your code leads to hang the excel application.
I tried `If Not cel.EntireRow.Hidden Then` and works more reliably

Comment: How huge is your selection?

Comment: Even with one cell

Comment: Try applying the selection to a range - then use that range - that worked for me.

Comment: Yes, It works perfectly by your last suggestion

Comment: I don't like using the selection object directly ... I updated the code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The credit of this working and more reliable answer @Tim Williams

```
If Not cel.EntireRow.Hidden Then
```